# Issue in reinstalling from old app to new

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-manifest

I am getting issue in reinstalling new app from old....First of all I had updated to latest version of android studio and my application is for private use and not on any playstore.
So here is my code:

```
package="com.xx.xxxxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1.1"
```

So when I had changed to :

```
package="com.xx.xxxxx"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1.2"
```

And now I am installing then it shows **App not installed**.I had searched from google and i had done all possible solution like using adb in command..but when we uninstall our current app and install the new version then it works well....but it should work automatically...grateful for help thank you

here is my messageview:
Error:Execution failed for task

':ftouch:packageDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key MyAndroidKey from store "C:\Users\Abhishek.android\debug.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Here is my Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wp.focus"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
}
 dependencies {
compile project(':aFileChooser')
compile project(':library_datepicker')
compile project(':library_numberprogress')
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/javax.activation.jar')
compile files('libs/javax-mail-1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
 }
```

Comment: any log available? what is the error?

Comment: Is app signed with different certificate? Did you use different PCs for developing old and new version, and signing it with DEBUG certificate?

Comment: actually no log available...I am taking new apk file and it can replace to old error is coming like App not installed..

Comment: yeah I am using different pc coz the old version was on other pc... @vladMatvienko

Comment: it may be issue with the signing keys. or try to post build.gradle and manifest files here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that your app was signed with DEBUG keystore/certificate (if you didn't sign it manually with other keystore).
In case it was developed on different PCs, each PC generates it's own DEBUG keystore.
This means that DEBUG version 1.1.2 app from one PC can't be installed over DEBUG version 1.1.1 app from the other PC.

There is no way currently to make it install over old version.
To avoid this in future, you have to create your own keystore, and sign APKs with it.
APK can be updated only if signed using same keystore/key.

Comment: thank you.....I am trying....if some issue will surely ask regarding this..

Comment: So here is my Issue well I had made new keystore and error is coming...Editted my question

Comment: @Abhi, you replaced debug keystore with your own?

Comment: you should not change debug keystore. You have to sign your app manually. Now you need firstly to make Android Studio generate new debug keystore. I think you can remove current, this way it should generate it. Then you need to manually sign your app (in main menu of Android Studio - Build - Generate signed APK), or configure gradle to sign it.

Comment: @Abhi, it is the same as .keystore file. You can create new one from that dialog as well.

Comment: can we transfer key store from old version to new version well thank you its working well but....as employees do have old version they must have to uninstall app once and its quite long way....is there any solution to transfer keystore from old pc to new. @vlad Matvienko

Comment: @Abhi, yes, you can take a file from old pc, and put it on the new pc to the debug keystore folder.

Comment: But I had already taken old project in my pc from other....Then what should be soln for that...??

Comment: Well can you make a time for me one more time....Where do I find keystore folder is it that folder where I had made keystore.jks ??or else where do i find coz i do have that same project coz I am using in same @Vlad Matvienko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128937/discussion-between-abhi-and-vlad-matvienko).